# Storing the output from a for loop into a list

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, ode

My code solves an ODE system using two random values of randomly generated parameters from a list. I put this in a for loop to generate some 50 outputs using those parameter values. I use an if loop within my for loop, to set conditions so that if the values calculated fall within a range, it prints an acceptance message, else print a rejection message. However, what I want is this information (the output values, and the corresponding param values used to generate those outputs) to be stored in memory, for example within a list. However my method only saves the last value in the list, or does not save anything in the list at all. Depending on how I position code within the loops, it will end up printing various elements 50 times in a row, which I do not want. My code is this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize


beta_samples = np.random.uniform(0, 30, 50)
gamma_samples = np.random.uniform(0, 2, 50)
for i, j in zip(beta_samples, gamma_samples):
    # Total population, N.
    N = 1
    # Initial number of infected and recovered individuals, I0 and R0.
    I0, R0 = 0.001, 0
    # Everyone else, S0, is susceptible to infection initially.
    U0 = N - I0 - R0
    J0 = I0
    Lf0, Ls0 = 0, 0
    # Contact rate, beta, and mean recovery rate, gamma, (in 1/days).
    beta, gamma = i, j
    mu, muTB, sigma, rho = 1/80, 1/6, 1/6, 0.03
    u, v, w = 0.88, 0.083, 0.0006
    t = np.linspace(0, 500, 500+1)
    
    # The SIR model differential equations.
    def deriv(y, t, N, beta, gamma, mu, muTB, sigma, rho, u, v, w):
        U, Lf, Ls, I, R, cInc = y
        b = (mu * (U + Lf + Ls + R)) + (muTB * I)
        lamda = beta * I
        clamda = 0.2 * lamda
        dU = b - ((lamda + mu) * U)
        dLf = (lamda*U) + ((clamda)*(Ls + R)) - ((u + v + mu) * Lf)
        dLs = (u * Lf) - ((w + clamda + mu) * Ls)
        dI = w*Ls + v*Lf - ((gamma + muTB + sigma) * I) + (rho * R)
        dR = ((gamma + sigma) * I) - ((rho + clamda + mu) * R)
        cI = w*Ls + v*Lf + (rho * R)
        return dU, dLf, dLs, dI, dR, cI
    
    
    # Integrate the SIR equations over the time grid, t.
    solve = odeint(deriv, (U0, Lf0, Ls0, I0, R0, J0), t, args=(N, beta, gamma, mu, muTB, sigma, rho, u, v, w))
    U, Lf, Ls, I, R, cInc = solve.T

    if 320 < I[-1]*100000 < 480 and 240 < (cInc[1:] - cInc[:-1])[-1]*100000 < 360:
        acc = [320 < I[-1]*100000 < 480]
        acc.append(320 < I[-1]*100000 < 480)
        print('for beta of', beta, 'and gamma of', gamma, 'pprevalence is ', I[-1]*100000, 'incidence is ', (cInc[1:] - cInc[:-1])[-1]*100000)
    else:
        rejected.append(beta_samples)
        print('values of', beta, 'and gamma of', gamma, 'rejected')
```

Where is my code going wrong? I simply want a list of the values that come under the 'if' conditions, and those coming under the 'else' conditions

Comment: does `acc.append(320 < I[-1]*100000 < 480)` want to be `accepted.append(...)`?

Comment: I just realised that `accepted=[]` has no reason to be in my code, ive edited it out.

Comment: Now you do not initialize any list. Even if done correctly, acc will be a list of `True`. Why do you append the full list of `beta_samples` to `rejected`? What is the special meaning of `i,j`, why not use `beta,gamma` from the start of the loop?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I think you edited the wrong way.  You variable `acc`appears to be of no use and I believe you want to append to  `accepted` like you append to `rejected`. However, I admit that is just from a quick overview rather than a real look at what you are doing.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I used i, j because of the for loop range, i wanted i to correspond to beta and j to gamma. Yes, I keep getting a list of `True`. But I dont understand why am I not getting a range of output values for `I[-1]` and `cInc[-1]` that satisfy the conditions in my `if`

Comment: That is because the computer does exactly what you tell it to do. You append logical conditions, you get logical values.